# QT Outline of textbox remains after pressing QPushButton

Tags: qt, qpushbutton

Newbie here.  Simple GUI, but after a pushbutton is selected and released, the outline of the pushbutton's text box stays until another pushbutton is selected and released, then it goes away, but then the same problem occurs in the latter pushbutton.

What do I need to do to eliminate the outline when button is released?

Comment: I think that you are talking about the rectangle that defines which widget currently has [the keyboard input focus](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#focus-prop). This is perfectly normal, the rectangle does not imply that the button is currently pressed, it simple means that button has the keyboard input focus. Why would you need to eliminate that?

Comment: You could explain better and show pictures that explain your case. Plus you attach your code.